# Homogeneous Linear Function Involving 2 Variables

Tags: linear-algebra

A function that looks like $y=mx$ is called a homogeneous linear function if it satisfies below equation:

$f(ax_1+bx_2)=af(x_1)+bf(x_2)$

Then if you have a function like $y=m_xx+m_yy$, what equation would it have to satisfy to be called a homogeneous linear function? I guess what is the equivalent version of $f(ax_1+bx_2)=af(x_1)+bf(x_2)$ for homogeneous linear functions involving 2 or more variables like $y=m_xx+m_yy$ above?

Comment: It is exactly the same equation except that you treat $x_1$ and $x_2$ as two-dimensional.

Comment: So like this? $af(x_1,y_1)+bf(x_2,y_2)=f(ax_1+bx_2,ay_1+by_2)$